# Sending String and Image to PHP script from android

Tags: android, post, http-post, httpclient, multipartentity

Im using this code to make **multipart entity** and send String and Image to a PHP page -

```
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);
            MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            entityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

            entityBuilder.addBinaryBody("Image", imageFile);              
            entityBuilder.addTextBody("name",name);

            HttpEntity entity = entityBuilder.build();
            post.setEntity(entity);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);           
            HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
            Log.d("result", EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity));
```

But **DefaultHttpClient** and **HttpPost** have been deprecated.

What should be the alternative code here ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use URL class:

```
 URL urlobj = new URL(url);
 HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlobj.openConnection();
 urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
 urlConnection.connect();
```